# Question about statement of axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Here is a statement of axiom of choice given in Folland's book Real Analysis.

If $\{X_\alpha\}$ is a nonempty collection of nonempty sets, then, $\Pi  X_\alpha$ is empty.

What does it mean to say "a nonempty collection"? Isn't it just enough to say that a collection of nonempty sets?

Comment: You mean $\prod X_\alpha$ is **nonempty**, probably.

Comment: I think it is to handle $\{\}$, which is a collection of nothing. As it doesn't contain anything, all the sets it "contains" are non-empty, but the product is empty...

Comment: @Dair Actually, the empty product contains exactly one element - the empty set.

Comment: @Wojowu My bad. My confusion seems to be reflected in Asaf's answer.

Comment: Perhaps you are having a "compilation error" so-to-speak . A collection is just a set. Once you replace collection for set everywhere you should have no problems reading it.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct to argue that if we take the empty collection, then $\prod_{\alpha\in\varnothing}X_\alpha$ is in fact $\{\varnothing\}$.

However, this is somewhat confusing, especially when you're coming to this not from a set theoretic point of view. And you want to avoid thinking about the empty product. Since there is only one collection which is empty (regardless to what you claim its elements to be), this is not any actual hindrance to anything practical when stating the axiom of choice.

This can also be attributed to the author not being very careful to examine the edge cases, and just chucking them aside altogether, which can often happen. Especially when the book is on a different topic (in this case, analysis and not set theory).

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different.  You could have an empty collection of well anything.  Whether that is required is another matter that others have answered.

My answer corrected thanks to Asaf's comment.

Comment: No, this is not true. The product over the empty set is not empty. Just like how $\varnothing^\varnothing\neq\varnothing$. (In fact, exactly like that.)

Comment: I was addressing the meaning of a non-empty collection but the follow on is indeed wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean to say "a nonempty collection"?

It means that the collection $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ itself is non-empty, i.e., that the indexing set $A$ is non-empty.

> Isn't it just enough to say that a collection of nonempty sets?

No, because $\emptyset$ is a collection of non-empty sets.

Comment: But the product over the empty set is non-empty. So in fact *every* collection of non-empty set has a non-empty product. Including the empty collection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree. I was addressing his questions, which I have quoted and which make no mention of products. I think I see the misunderstanding: my answer is with respect to the question "Isn't it just enough to say that a collection of nonempty sets (implies a non-empty collection of non-empty sets)?", while yours concerns the question "Isn't it just enough to say that a collection of nonempty sets (implies a non-empty product)?" It's not obvious to me what OP means exactly (but hopefully everything is clear now).

Comment: Yes, I see now how someone would read the question this way. I guess we should ask the OP to clarify.

Comment: @AsafKaragilaWhat I meant to ask was that when the author says "nonempty collection" I thought that it meant the indexing set $A$ is non-empty, but then I was confused b/c if $A$ is empty, isn't the whole discussion vacuous? It seems redundant to me to insist $A$ is non-empty. By vacuous, I mean, what is the point of considering collection when the index set is empty?

Comment: @nan: Well, the discussion is actually not vacuous when $A$ is empty. It is trivial, since the product over the empty index happens to be non-empty. As I explained in my answer.